# what's the padding mode used when use crypto:des_ecb_encrypt/2 in erlang

Tags: erlang, cryptography, padding, des

I'm just confused about what's the padding mode used when use crypto:des_ecb_encrypt/2 in erlang. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Eh, it does not seem to do any padding, if I'm not mistaken. You may have to pad/unpad yourself. Could you try and encrypt a single byte or char? If it fails, you are operating without padding. If it works, try decrypting and see if the output matches. If it doesn't, some kind of automatic but undefined padding is performed.

Comment: Just for my information, what does that /2 mean?

Comment: function/2 is syntax for a function of arity 2 (two arguments).

Comment: Ah, ok. Well, looking at the source code you need to provide exactly N*blocksize of data, so no padding. The only padding I see mentioned regarding erlang is PKCS#1 padding, but that's for RSA. PKCS#5/7 padding is not hard to do: you simply extend the plain text with bytes valued 01, 02 02 up to 08 08 08 08 08 08 08 08 until you get to the next full blocksize. Unpadding: remove the same number of bytes, the number of bytes is decoded in the bytes themselves.

Comment: obligitory point :  don't use ECB mode. Also don't use DES for anything where security maters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find out, encrypt some plaintext that is not a whole number of blocks.  Decrypt it with "no padding" set, and see what the encryption process added to the end of the last block.

If encryption fails, then it is probably expecting you to add your own padding first.  As has been said, use PKCS5 or PKCS7 padding.

Comment: I didn't post it as an answer because I didn't know for certain what kind of padding was used rossum, your answer is basically my comments, without telling the actual padding mechanism.

Comment: I gave you a way to find out what padding mechanism was being used: decrypt with "no padding" and look at the padding added to the last block.

Comment: Never mind rossum, I was making the comments, not asking the question. And I had already proposed to encrypt a single byte and decrypt the output - I just did not put it down as an answer, because it isn't a directly usable one.